# How to map transparency for video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, transparency

I have a list of images which have transparent background (png files). While I convert them to `mp4` this transparency is mapped as white color. How to make it either transparent (whether it's possible) or black?

I used code:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i e:/gals/0/logo%03d.png -loop -1 -pix_fmt yuva420p e:/gals/1/logo.mp4
```

It's the same situation while I save it as gif. M

Maybe it's important - those images have been made from others using this format: `-vf "format=bgra,rotate=-2*PI/180:c=black@0"`.

**EDIT**

I guess I found solution quickly. Just saved this initial image before rotation not as `png` but as `tiff` with transparency, LZW compression, no layers. Those rotated can be `png`. There was some format issue from source image or something what I don't understand.